# How to make Parse work with Xamarin's PCL project and MvvmCross?

Tags: c#, parsing, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am having a lot of problems when trying to integrate [Parse](http://www.parse.com) with cross-platform Xamarin app. At first, I was able to create Android app using Xamarin and MvvmCross and integrate with Parse service (done by adding Parse component in Xamarin). When it comes time to develop iOS app, I am having problem to refactor out Parse dependency into Core PCL project, since Parse currently doesn't support Xamarin PCL projects. Hence, there is no Parse NuGet package or Xamarin component that can be added to PCL project. I can easily add Parse component to iOS project and Android project respectively, but that will require lots of code duplication across both projects.

I've read that referencing Parse.dll and Parse.NetFx45.dll in Core project enables me to use Parse calls in Core project. I did this and are able to compile everything successfully. However, when I try to initialize Parse in Core project using `ParseClient.Initialize("ApplicationID", "DotNetKey");`, I get `TypeInitializationException` during runtime.

Question is, what is the best way to integrate Parse service with Xamarin & MvvmCross cross-platform application? I'd imagine lots of people would have done this, but couldn't find references/examples. Duplicating codes across both iOS and Android project definitely shouldn't be the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a couple of ideas:

First, if you are currently manually copying Parse code changes from project to project, you could speed up that process by writing a script that you run that would clone certain files to the other project. Or you could maybe write a grunt script that copies files automatically when it detects a change.

Now, here is another approach that stores Parse code in one project but is shared across platforms:

**The Problem:** I was using a Shared Project instead of a PCL to house my Xamarin.Forms and Parse code. The Parse code was working just fine, but I ran into an issue when trying to use my own custom ContentView in my ContentPage in XAML. I wanted a solution that would allow my custom ContentView to work as well as my Parse code -- both from the same project.

**The Solution:** I have switched to now housing my Xamarin.Forms and Parse code in a PCL. But there is a small catch. Before I explain the catch, just know that it does work with NO Parse code duplication (except for the one line of Parse initialization code that goes in each platform's specific project).

**What's the catch?** The catch is that in your portable class library you have to manually swap in and out either the Parse.iOS.dll or Parse.Android.dll depending on what you are compiling for at the time.

**Does it increase the file size?** No. I tested with my app using a Shared Project (where it uses the platform project's referene to the Parse dll) versus a Portable Class Library (where you have to add a reference to the dll in the platform's project as well as the PCL) and found no increase in the app file size by doing it this way.

Below is the project structure that is currently working for me (with project names renamed for confidentiality). (FYI: I am using Xamarin for Mac.)

```
MyProject.iOS
 - Reference to Parse.iOS.dll
 - Reference to the Portable Class Library
MyProject.Android
 - Reference to Parse.iOS.dll
 - Reference to the Portable Class Library
Portable Class Library
 - Parse Code
 - Xamarin Forms Code
 - Reference to either Parse.iOS.dll or Parse.Android.dll
```

**Important**: When swapping out the DLL in the PCL, I found that if I right-click the DLL under the References menu, and then click Delete, it caused issues in my project where the iOS project wouldn't compile anymore because it was still looking for the Parse.Android.dll or vice-versa. I tried cleaning the solution, deleting bin and obj folders from the solution's file system to no avail. I got it to work again by doing this: Right-click References, click Edit References, and then uncheck the one Parse DLL and check the box for the other. However, then after that, I tried the "Delete" method again and didn't have problems compiling. Who knows, maybe that issue will crop up for me again.

**Won't this get annoying?** Depending on how often you switch between platforms, the manual swapping of DLLs may or may not get annoying. No matter how annoying that is though, it can't be worse than having duplicate code. (Perhaps this swapping process could be automated with a script? I think you'd have to unload the PCL and reload it though if you modify the .csproj with a script. Anyone out there up for the challenge? Or perhaps there is a way to do a conditional reference to the DLL based on the platform it is compiling for. Thoughts anyone?)

I hope this helps. If you like any of these ideas better than what you are currently doing please accept this as the answer and let us know which route you decide to take.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the best way to to this, to create a Parse Plugin for Mvvmcross? Where you define your interfaces that want to use.

And in each platform specific library you reference the parse dll and call the method. So in you Core project you should be able to call the IParse.methods...

Comment: Good idea, but it will still lead to duplication codes because the codes for both platforms are exactly the same. The only difference between the two platforms is the dll that needs to be referenced.

Comment: Yeah, but then you can create something just like the SQLite aplugin... A shared code in Core that is used for all platforms, they are added as link in the specifics platforms plugins

Answer (score 0):

So I got it working fine on both Android and iOS by referencing Parse.Android.dll in all 3 projects (Core, iOS, and Android). Yes it sounds weird, but that's what's working for me. Just go to [Parse download page](https://www.parse.com/docs/downloads) and download Xamarin SDK under Android section. It works wonders too! No code duplications, no mess :)

Comment: Note that on iOS, when doing it this way, Mono.Android runtime will need to be included in iOS, causing the app size to be _huge_! Maybe this is not the best way after all :(

Comment: Did you ever find a nice way to make Parse work for both iOS and Android without duplicating Parse logic and without making the iOS app huge?

Comment: @AnthonyTietjen We ended up putting the codes that need interaction with Parse into a class in platform specific projects. These classes implement an interface that is defined in Core. So, let's say I want to query for total number of sales in my ViewModel located in Core, I will call `await ISomeParse.GetNumberOfSales()`. The codes in Droid/iOS classes are identical (except the namespace), and they implement the same interface. So unfortunately there are code duplications involved, but it works quite well. When you want to update the code, make sure the other copy in other project is updated.

Comment: @AnthonyTietjen Also, in each platform specific projects, put reference to respective Parse dlls - Parse.Touch.dll for iOS, Parse.Droid.dll for Droid. If you found a better way, please let us all know :)

Comment: A better solution is explained by SharpMobileCode at this URL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30228621/parse-and-xamarin (Make sure to see what I added to his response.) I have confirmed that that solution works for my iOS project with a shared class library. I haven't confirmed it for Android since I don't have an Android Xamarin license right now for Xamarin.Forms, but I would highly expect it to work.

Comment: @AnthonyTietjen great idea to host the Parse codes into a Shared Project. At first I thought of doing that but somehow I thought the whole codebase needs to be migrated from a PCL into a Shared Project, but now I realize I can just put Parse code in Shared Project, and leave the others inside PCL. Thanks :) You might want to create a proper answer to this question and I can mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: I have just found a limitation to hosting the Xamarin.Forms files in a Shared Project instead of a Portable Class Library. (I should have pointed out earlier I am using Xamarin Forms.) Anyway, since I have my Xamarin Forms code in a Shared Project, that limits me from being able to embed a ContentView into my ContentPage. So from what I can tell, depending on the project type: you win some, you lose some... Read more about it the ContentView issue here: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/128136