# Parse and Xamarin

Tags: parse-platform, xamarin

I am using Xamarin and I was wondering if there is a way to run Parse in a shared project, so that I don't have to duplicate my code in the iOS project and the Android project in my solution?

Am I missing something, or do I really have to duplicate the Parse code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did was create a [Shared Project](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/shared_projects/) type to host my Parse specific Code.  Then in my Xamarin.Android app, I reference the Parse.Android.dll.  In my Xamarin.iOS code, I referenced the Parse.iOS.dll.  Remember, that the ["Shared Project"](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/shared_projects/) type does not create a DLL.  Underneath the hood it's just file linking into your actual project, so it will use the references of that project.  The Shared Project should not contain any iOS or Android specific code.

Comment: To clarify, your Android and iOS projects also both need to have a reference to the Shared Project. Also, it does not seem to work when the shared project is a Portable Class Library. Instead it has to be a regular class library.

Comment: Well, glad you got it working, but I think you're using the term "Shared Project" incorrectly.  If you read the links above, a "Shared Project" is an actual Project Type.  It's just File Linking underneath the hood and compiles under the context of either an iOS or Android project. No DLL is compiled for a Shared Project.  A PCL is different in that it actually compiles into a DLL and can be referenced by any type of project it supports (Profile 78 supports all Xamarin based projects).  You can still have your main Core as a PCL, but only have your Parse stuff code in a "Shared Project".

Comment: This link here explains the difference between a Shared Project and a Portable Class Library and when you might choose one over the other.

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/building_cross_platform_applications/sharing_code_options/